# android scroll text to the left when last character become in the middle of edittext

Tags: android

is there any way to scroll text to the left when last character become in the middle of edit text rather than the end as shown in the picture[image]

when text reaches the arrow i need to scroll the text to the left and prevent it from approaching the text "@gmail.com"

I searched a lot but I did not know the term required for it
this is my code

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/emailMainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/upPasswordLayout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gmailText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="58dp"
        android:text="@gmail.com"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textSize="@dimen/edit_text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/emailLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/emailLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:counterMaxLength="30"
        app:counterOverflowTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
        app:counterTextAppearance="@style/counter_appearance"
        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/hint_appearance">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_email_black"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textNoSuggestions"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textDirection="ltr"
            android:textSize="@dimen/edit_text"
            android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an `EditText` with transparent background and put a `TextView` beside it (with "@gmail.com" text), then put a fake line below it, in order to make an `EditText` like display.
The code below displays how you can achieve such a thing.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

        // Place this TextView beside the EditText
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="\@gmail.com" />

        // Icon
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:src="EXAMPLE_IMAGE_SRC"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    // Displays a line which will feel like the whole view is an EditText
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: the problem is that i am using input text layout for floating label and error text

Comment: Just Replace the `InputTextLayout` with `EditText` in my code. the and set its background to `transparent`. You shouldn't have any problem displaying errors.

Comment: thanks for replying, but what about the drawable icon

Comment: @phoenix That's the easy part! I'll update my answer with the drawable.

Comment: @phoenix I've updated the answer and added the icon.

Comment: thanks again
i really need a solution including scrolling state because your solution does not include a lot of cases like other edit text above this one , floating label , input text layout counter and hint

Answer (score -1):

You should use `android:gravity="right"`.you can use it in layout or you can also set it pragmatically after edittext text changed.

```
 EditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    EdiText.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

   }

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {

   }
  });
```

Comment: gravity for what case?

Comment: for text to move left or right after user type the text in edittext